# Call a model not from database to list ASP.NET Core 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have these 3 models:

```
public class Example1
{
    public int ID_Ex1 { get; set; }
    public int Attr1 { get; set; }
    public int Attr2 { get; set; }
    public int Attr3 { get; set; }
}

public class Example2
{
    public int ID_Ex2 { get; set; }
    public int Attr3 { get; set; }
    public int Attr4 { get; set; }
    public int Attr5 { get; set; }
    public virtual Example1 example1 { get; set; }
}

public class Example3
{
    public int ID_Ex3 { get; set; }
    public int Attr6 { get; set; }
    public int Attr7 { get; set; }
    public int Attr8 { get; set; }
    public virtual Example1 example1 { get; set; }
}
```

and the ViewModel, I took all attributes from the model above (just in case):

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    // Example 1
    public int ID_Ex1 { get; set; }
    public int Attr1 { get; set; }
    public int Attr2 { get; set; }
    public int Attr3 { get; set; }
    // Example 2
    public int ID_Ex2 { get; set; }
    public int Attr3 { get; set; }
    public int Attr4 { get; set; }
    public int Attr5 { get; set; }
    // Example 3
    public int ID_Ex3 { get; set; }
    public int Attr6 { get; set; }
    public int Attr7 { get; set; }
    public int Attr8 { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller, how do I return `ExampleViewModel.ToList()` for showing the data in the `Index` view, or is there another way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't. Maybe you could explain what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: The `example1,example2,example3` is in database, you want to get the value of them and Combine their values ​​into the same class?

Comment: I combined all of model to one view and insert data After I inserted I want to show data to index view using IEnumerable by return ExampleViewModel.ToList() in Index Controller. But it doesnt work, so i have to find another way to return it to list. Sorry for lacking of information.

Comment: can you provide the code about how you combine the value in controller?  What does `But it doesnt work,` mean? Is it show any error message? `ExampleViewModel` is just a class, it can't be `.tolist()` directly.

Comment: If what you want is a list then why do you have a flat model in the first place? Again, explain what you're trying to achieve rather than how you're trying to achieve it.

Comment: I'm trying to create a view for a ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Generally, When using `ViewModel`, We just put the Model we need in ViewModel instead of their properties. `ViewModel` is just a model passed data  between controller and View, You can't just use `ExampleViewModel.ToList()` directly.

From your question, I think you just want to pass List of `ExampleViewModel` from controller to view, And i also noticed that you have `one-to-one` relationship in your models, So i write a simple demo here, You can refer to it.

For tesing convenience, I just change the properties to Name

```
public class Example1
{
    public int ID_Ex1 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
}

public class Example2
{
    public int ID_Ex2 { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Example1 example1 { get; set; }
}

//.......
```

**ExampleViewModel**

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public Example1 Example1s { get; set; }
    public List<Example2> Example2s { get; set; }
    public List<Example3> Example3s { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<ExampleViewModel> models = new List<ExampleViewModel>();
        
        //select all Example1 from db frist
        var example1s =   _dbContext.Example1.ToList();
        
        foreach (var example in example1s)
        {
            ExampleViewModel exampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
            
            //select Example2 and Example3 corresponding to Example1
            var example2 =  _dbContext.Example2.Where(x => x.example1.ID_Ex1 == example.ID_Ex1).ToList(); 
            var example3 = _dbContext.Example3.Where(x => x.example1.ID_Ex1 == example.ID_Ex1).ToList();
            exampleViewModel.Example1s = example;
            exampleViewModel.Example2s = example2;
            exampleViewModel.Example3s = example3;
            models.Add(exampleViewModel);
            
        }
        
        return View(models);
    }
```

**Then in the view, You can use `@foreach()` to get each item of `list<ExampleViewModel>`**

[image]

I hope it is what you want.

Comment: That's what im trying to get, worked as expected. Thanks very much.